# How to create new table in PostgreSQL from existing table that has columns with distinct row values?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table, pgadmin-4

I have table **tansactions** that looks like this -
[image]

I want to make a separate **customers** table that has distinct 'customer_code' in ascending order and related 'market_code','market_name', and 'zone' columns.
the resultant table would look like this -
[image]

I have tried -

```
create table customers as (
select customer_code, market_code, market_name, zone 
from transactions group by customer_code);
```

This works fine on MySQL workbench but doesn't work on PGadmin.

[image]

Comment: PGadmin deals with PostgreSQL, not with MySQL. In PostgreSQL CREATE TABLE AS does not allow the parenthesis (moreover, in MySQL too, but MySQL forgives such mistakes).

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the question. Removing parenthesis didn't work. Even grouping with the remaining column would make a table with non-distinct column values.

Comment: Remove GROUP BY but add DISTINCT.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT customer_code, market_code, market_name, zone 
FROM transactions; It has non-distinct column values.

Comment: *It has non-distinct column values.* It seems that the claimed task and the needed one are not the same. Show these "non-distinct columns values" sample (for one definite customer_code) and all source rows which results in these rows occured in the output.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order for the customer_code field to have unique values ​​in this table, the other fields cannot have different values ​​in the transactions table for the same customer_code, for example, if it is possible for a customer_code to have different values ​​in the market_code, market_name or zone fields, in different rows of the transactions table so this calls for a clustering strategy that you haven't considered.

The GROUP BY clause requires some aggregation function like SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG, etc... in MySQL when you don't use any of that it brings the first row found ensuring the grouping of what was requested in the GROUP BY , in PostgreSQL this does not happen, the aggregation function is required on ungrouped fields.

Below I give an example of how to work breaking up tables without creating views or something else, which makes it easier for complex issues like your question. Maybe if you are more specific in the question it will be easier to give a better answer.

```
CREATE TABLE customers AS 
WITH STEP_A AS (
    SELECT 
        T.customer_code
        , COUNT(T.customer_code) AS TOT
    FROM
        transactions T 
    GROUP BY
        T.customer_code 
)
, STEP_B AS (
    SELECT 
        A.customer_code 
    FROM
        STEP_A A
    INNER JOIN 
        transactions T 
        ON A.customer_code = T.customer_code 
    WHERE 
        A.TOT = 1
)

SELECT 
    B.* 
FROM 
    STEP_B B 
ORDER BY
    B.customer_code ASC
;
```

Hope this helps!! Good luck!

Comment: This will exclude any customer with more than one transaction. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If you used the distinct in the select and still brought repeated customer_code, it is because one of the other fields has more than one value for the same customer_code, so it would be necessary to group using some function like SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN, etc, in the fields that do not are the customer_code. Only then would it bring unique values to the customer_code field. In the question there is no defined strategy for the grouping if there are different values for the same customer, it is only asked how to make a table using a select with unique customer_codes.

Comment: If in the transactions table there were only values that were always the same for these fields, a simple distinct in a common select would solve it. As they didn't ask defining a strategy for these other fields, I answered the question showing what it would be like without bringing what "was not foreseen in the original question".

Comment: I agree the question was incomplete. Your answer doesn't work for the original question though. If one customer has two transactions, with identical value in the four relevant columns, that customer would still not shown in the result set of your query.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking two questions:

1. Why does my create table statement run in MySQL and not in postgreSQL?
2. How to write the proper create table statement?

### MySQL vs. PostgreSQL

As to the first question: Your query is invalid. You group by customer_code and select the market_code. But there are many rows for one customer_code, so which of its market_codes to pick? You forgot to tell the DBMS. Hence both DBMS should throw an error. If MySQL doesn't, this probably means that you are working with an old MySQL version that is set to a cheat mode that MySQL invented when they had problems with `GROUP BY` clauses and functional dependencies ín the beginning. Make sure to `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` in MySQL to get a proper syntax error message when wrting such invalid queries - or use a current MySQL version where this mode is the default.

As to the second question, this is not so easy to answer...

### Database normalization

You are dealing with a non-normalized table. It shows the same customer in the same market in the same zone again and again. And this is prone to errors. You expect the same customer to always be in the same market, but what if this isn't the case with some transactions? You expect a code belonging to exactly one market name, but what if this is not always the case in the table? You expect one market to be in one zone, and again, what if this is not the case with all transactions?

Let's say that all your expectations are valid, and data violating these expectations is erroneous.

### Correcting inconsistencies

So, find data inconsistencies first. I am using PostgreSQL here as this seems to be what you want to use in spite of the MySQL tag.

```
select customer_code, string_agg(distinct market_code, ',' order by market_code)
from transactions
group by customer_code
having count(distinct market_code) > 1;
```

If this query retuns customers with more than one markt, fix your data. E.g.:

```
update transactions
set market_code = 'Mark001'
where customer_code = 'Cus001';
```

Same for market codes. The query:

```
select market_code, string_agg(distinct market_name, ',' order by market_name)
from transactions
group by market_code
having count(distinct market_name) > 1;
```

Update of inconsistent data:

```
update transactions
set market_name = 'Darbhanga'
where market_code = 'Mark001';
```

Same for market zones. The query:

```
select market_code, string_agg(distinct zone, ',' order by zone)
from transactions
group by market_code
having count(distinct zone) > 1;
```

Update of inconsistent data:

```
update transactions
set zone = 'Bihar'
where market_code = 'Mark001';
```

### Normalizing the database

Once this is done, build your tables. Yes, not one customer table alone, because this would still be non-normalized and bear the same risk. Instead, we have zones, markets, customers, and transactions.

You can use technical IDs or stick to your codes alone. I am building the tables based on your codes here, but the choice is yours.

### Zones

```
create table zone
(
  zone_code varchar(100) not null,
  zone      varchar(100) not null,
  primary key (zone_code),
  unique (zone)
);

insert into zone (zone_code, zone)
  select distinct upper(zone), zone
  from transactions;
```

### Markets

```
create table market
(
  market_code varchar(100) not null,
  name        varchar(100) not null,
  zone_code   varchar(100) not null,
  primary key (market_code),
  unique (name),
  constraint fk_market_zone foreign key(zone_code) references zone(zone_code)
);

insert into market (market_code, name, zone_code)
  select distinct market_code, market_name, upper(zone)
  from transactions;
```

### Customers

```
create table customer
(
  customer_code varchar(100) not null,
  market_code varchar(100) not null,
  primary key (customer_code),
  constraint fk_customer_market foreign key(market_code) references market(market_code)
);

insert into customer (customer_code, market_code)
  select distinct customer_code, market_code
  from transactions;
```

### Transactions

Remove the now redundant columns from the table. They are now implicit with the customer.

```
alter table transactions
  drop column market_code,
  drop column market_name,
  drop column zone;
```

Comment: Thanks, for the elaborated solution and for pointing out the basic problem within the data.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You simply need a DISTINCT clause -

```
CREATE TABLE customers as
SELECT DISTINCT customer_code, market_code, market_name, zone 
  FROM transactions;
```

Comment: The columns has non distinct (duplicate) values

Comment: Can you please post that non duplicate data and expected result as text  not as image.

Comment: can I share screen

Comment: @atif If a customer code has nondistict values, what logic should be used to determine the output? Your MySQL code just randomly / arbitrarily chooses a row to use, is that what you want??

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to create temporary table from select customer_code, market_code, market_name, zone? Then from the temp table try to do the distinct and group by.

Answer (score -1):

Hi add DISTINCT in your Query and group all columns and save this as csv.
PostgreSQL Import CSV later.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       customer_code -- 1
      ,market_code   -- 2
      ,market_name   -- 3
      ,zone          -- 4

   FROM transactions 
   GROUP by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: With your code the column has duplicates.

Answer (score -2):

following table create table with name Customers

```
with cte as(
  select customer_code from transactions
    group by customer_code
  )select * into customers from cte
```

Comment: If you read the other answers here, the op has already said why that doesn't work for them.

Comment: I am Creating table with the Result using **common table expression** It will work @MatBailie

Comment: No. In multiple places the op has pointed out that their data is not unique across those four columns, and that this will therefore yield duplicate entries for some customers. They have Not explained what logic they want to implement to deal with this. Either way, the OP has already explained why the logic inside your CTE doesn't work for their needs.

Comment: @MatBailie changes are made accordingly Distinct Customers into table